# Text files with sections in common with a given file

Tags: filesystems, scripting, trap

I need to maintain a set of plain text files saved in a directory which all have a section taken from another file. An example follows:

Files:

```
/directory/textfile1 (every other file in the directory needs to "include" the
                      full contents of this file, each file can do so at a
                      different starting position; this file changes often      )
/directory/textfile2 ("includes" textfile1 after a few lines from the top       )
/directory/textfile3 ("includes" textfile1 as a header                          )
/directory/textfile4 ("includes" textfile1 as a footer                          )
```

Upon changing textfile1, I would like filesystem reads hitting textfile{2..4} to
return updated versions with the new content from textfile1.

On web servers, this would be solved with the traditional server side include
directives. Now, how would I do that without running a front-end service?

Could I create a symlink that, rather than pointing to another inode,
runs some custom code and presents stdout as the contents of the file, somehow like
defining custom "reparse points"?

The hypotetical "symlink" would, for instance, run this for file textfile3:

```
cat /directory/textfile1 /directory/textfile3_static
```

and thus simulate the existence of a static file whose content depends on textfile1.

I am looking for a solution that uses the least amount of customisation, not writing
a custom FUSE module for a special mount point or anything like that.

I may be thinking in the wrong direction here, perhaps it would be easier to trigger
an update script replacing placeholders at every modification of textfile1? How
could one trap that event without polling for it?

Here some sample text files:

Contents:

```
/directory/textfile1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ferma non stai sei come un ciclone
e non dormi mai
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/directory/textfile2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Juny tu hai un cervellone
quasi tutto sai
Ma quando fai un'invenzione
sono sempre guai
Ferma non stai sei come un ciclone
e non dormi mai
Il centauro Nico ami già
ma lui forse non lo sa
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/directory/textfile3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ferma non stai sei come un ciclone
e non dormi mai
Il centauro Nico ami già
ma lui forse non lo sa

Come sempre insisterai
allora che pasticci tu di nuovo farai
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

... etcetera. :)

Comment: Would it be acceptable for you to use read-wrapper-scripts?

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: read-wrapper-scripts? As in? Could you provide an example or an elucidatory link, please?

Comment: I meant scripts that you'd execute instead of reading each file. But I see the answers about named pipes achieve this in a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translating somehow the @polynomial answer to `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! -e textfile2 ]]; then
  mkfifo textfile2
fi

while true; do
  (
    exec >textfile2
    cat textfile2-header
    cat textfile1
    cat textfile2-footer
  )
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with named pipes.  Basically you would maintain your text files somewhere as 'templates' and a script like this perl example:

http://perl.active-venture.com/pod/perlipc-pipes.html

Would open 'textfile3' as a pipe and when it got a read request it would dump the contents that textfile3 should contain (perhaps by reading textfile3.template and replacing the contents as needed).  This would allow you to dynamically change the contents without having to update multiple files and with minimal configuration.